# Не удаляется инофрмация при SoftDelete на странице index

Tags: php, laravel

Есть две модели - Сотрудники и Сертификаты сотрудников. Для них две разные страницы index. Когда я делаю SoftDelete сотрудника, затем перехожу на страницу Сертификатов, я все еще продолжаю видеть этого сотрудника в списке сертификатов (имя сотрудника). Исчезает он только тогда, когда делаю полное удаление. А как сделать так, чтобы при softDelete запись на странице все равно пропадала?

**EmployeeCertificates index.blade.php:**

```
                       [
                            'attribute' => function($item) { return $item->employee->name; },
                            'label' => 'Сотрудник',
                            'style' => 'width: 30%; min-width: 200px;',
                            'filter' => [
                                'class' => \App\View\Components\Filters\Select::class,
                                'params' => [
                                    'name' => 'employee_id',
                                    'options' => $employees->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray(),
                                    'value' => request()->get('employee_id', ''),
                                    'htmlAttributes' => '',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
```

**Employee model:**

```
    public function certificates(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmployeeCertificate::class, 'employee_id');
    }
```

**EmployeeCertificates model:**

```
    public function employee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужно хранить сертификаты удаленных сотрудников, то просто добавьте в контроллере в метод удаления сотрудников доп. правило.

**EmployeeController.php**

```
...

public function destory(Request $request, Employee $employee)
{
    $employee->certificates()->delete();
    $employee->delete();

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение. Добавить в модель `Employee` функцию `boot`:

```
    public function certificates(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EmployeeCertificate::class, 'employee_id');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($offer) {
            $offer->certificates()->delete();
        });
    }
```